# Prove that $\sum_{i=2}^n \sqrt{i}$ is irrational for all $n \geq 2$

Tags: summation, irrational-numbers

**Question:** Prove that $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{i}$ is irrational for all $n \geq 2$.

**My attempts:** My first instict was going straight to proving this with mathematical induction, however I'm unsure how this would work as if $n$ if a square number it may be a little problematic with the $n=k+1$ case. Perhaps there is another way of doing it that doesn't require mathematical induction. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Actually, [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3356649/for-integer-n1-can-sum-k-1n-sqrtk-be-a-rational-number-can-it-be) has the right title and proves it, too, but is a duplicate of the above.